# Taking users from Offer's T&C page to Listing or Details page?

Tags: usability, website-design, user-behavior, mobile-application, mobile-web

**Case:**
In my e-commerce website/mobile-site/mobile-app, we run offers that are shown on PDP (Product Details page). These offers are a bit complicated and hence a detailed T&C page has been created to explain all the details around the same.

**User journey:**
User searches for offers on google - The T&C page of my offer has been indexed by Google and is hence it's link is shown to the User - User clicks on the link - User arrives at T&C page of the offer - User reads the complete T&C of the offer - There is a link on this T&C page that will take user to Listing page (where all the items, on which the offer is applicable are listed) - User clicks on the link - User is taken to the listing page - User chooses his item on the listing page and clicks on the same - User is taken to the PDP of the item - User reads the offer's text on the PDP (this re-affirms him that he is on the correct journey to avail the offer) - User adds the item to cart; thus availing the offer; and eventually buys the same.

**Question:**
Assume this journey now: User comes to my website - User arrives at PDP of an item that he would like to buy - User reads the offer's text on the PDP - User also sees a T&C link below the offer's text (This is the link to same T&C page of the offer, that I mentioned in the previous journey) - User clicks on the T&C link - User arrives at T&C page of the offer - There is a link on this T&C page that will take user to Listing page (where all the items, on which the offer is applicable are listed)

Now, the question is that **how will the user go back to the PDP that he just came from? Should user click on the link on this T&C page that will take user to Listing page and then he should search for his item there? Should I expect him to use Browser's or Device's back button?**

Comment: Can you explain if the T&C's are a legal requirement to be displayed? This is integral as to where the copy is show and whether you can get away with a lightbox of T&C's on the PDP rather than taking the user away to the free format details page.

Answer (score 1):

I see it this way:

User click on the offers link/banner/etc, user arrives at the offers page, now there are two options.

Option 1:
User picks a product, the product button is disabled until user tick "I agree to terms and conditions", which contains a link that opens a modal window where the terms are described.

Option 2: 
Product description contain terms and conditions and fine print that states "by proceeding with this purchase you agree to terms and condition [link]".

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to determine what your priorities are for the journey. Are you more interested in getting the user to checkout from the current PDP or would you prefer them to view more products within the offer?

I'm assuming the priority is to get the customer to checkout from the current PDP.

I think you're journey should start in the PLP with all of the products within the offer. This is how I would set up your journey:

1. User arrives to the offer by clicking on banner for the offer, or maybe from a marketing email.
2. User gets taken to the PLP with all of the products within the offer. Potentially highlight any important details of the T&C's somewhere at the top of the PLP (Like if the customer needs to use a discount code for example) with a link to more info. **If the user clicks on more info open a new browser window with T&C info (target="_blank"), this will allow them to get back to the PLP with ease by closing the new window or hitting the back button**.
3. If the user clicks on a product load up the PDP, and on the PDP have a clear interaction about the offer terms and conditions (more info), **if they click this follow the same pattern of opening a new window with terms and conditions.** If the user needs to see more products in the offer they can go back from the PDP page back to the PLP, because this is where they initially came from.

So to clarify:

Link to offer --> Offer PLP (all products) --> PDP [T&C's link opens in new window]

Answer (score 1):

There is a great chance that the user will miss the T&C links on the PDP. Let the user reads out the offer details and hit the 'Add to Cart' button. Then show the T&C on a pop-up with 'Continue' button. Also, display the T&C link next to the product name on the shopping cart so that users can refer back before they make the payment.

Answer (score 1):

I would hide the T&Cs during product search and selection.

Allow access to T&Cs before the product search. New page link from landing page. Place a T&Cs agreement check box before final checkout. The words "Terms & Conditions" should be a clickable link to overlay with T&Cs Description. Read and close overlay to return to checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rerouting can you not keep the user within the product selection flow and simply reuse the T&C page? On this page instead of having a link to the listing page have two buttons: back to product details and proceed to buy.

This way the user will never leave the product buying cycle and will seamlessly move back and forth.